# Undefinded html attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, undefined

I am trying to load an image when a thumb is clicked on. The user clicks on:

```
<li><a href="#" class="01"><img src="images/thumbimg1.jpg" alt="thumbnail 1" /></a></li>
```

And the jQuery i'm using is:

```
var divs = $('#img01, #img02, #img03, #img04, #img05, #img06, #img07, #img08, #img09, #img10');
var classNumber = $(this).attr('class');
var thumb = 'thumb';
var html = '.html';
$(divs).hide();

//$("#img01" + $(this).attr("class")).load(thumb+number+html).fadeIn();

$('ul#thumbs li a').click(function(){
    $(divs).hide();
    $('#img' + $(this).attr('class')).load(thumb+classNumber+html).fadeIn();
});
});
```

When i look at the console, classNumber just comes back as undefined.

When i do console.log(this); i get the correct link clicked which shows the correct class, so i have no idea why i'm getting undefined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting undefined because:

```
var classNumber = $(this).attr('class');
```

is being bound outside of the loop, so this doesn't refer to the element and instead refers to the window. In the code above, you're trying effectively trying to do this:

```
var classNumber = $(window).attr('class');
```

You need to do this instead:

```
$('ul#thumbs li a').click(function(){
    var classNumber = $(this).attr('class');
    $(divs).hide();
    $('#img' + $(this).attr('class')).load(thumb+classNumber+html).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I now get the classNumber, but all the divs are display: none; even when a thumb is clicked on.

Comment: Are you able tp provide a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) of your code? It might make it easier to debug. The .load method expects a URL as it's a shorthand method for Ajax. The parameter you're passing in to the .load() is (for example) "thumb01.html" have you checked this path is correct? In this example I've added the callback to the load method to log what the response text is from that URL, try that to see if the ajax call is actually working http://jsfiddle.net/KYaVX/ - I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Worked it out. Thanks for your help anyway. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `classNumber` variable is being declared outside the scope of the particular `a` that was clicked on. Instead, you need to define it inside the click handler;

```
$('ul#thumbs li a').click(function(){
    var classNumber = $(this).attr('class');

    $(divs).hide();
    $('#img' + $(this).attr('class')).load(thumb+classNumber+html).fadeIn();
});
```

---

FWIW, you might want to chose another attribute rather than `class`, as this will break if you add other classes later in life. Use either a custom attribute (`data-*`), or steal another attribute such as `title`.

You also might want to look at adding a common class to all your `#img`'s, and simply calling `$(.your-common-class)` rather than each of them individually.